# EF Core results with a field value exists in array

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to get users data that user `StatusId` exists in an array that includes the status ids I need.

I use the following code but the results is the last value in my array.

```
int[] statusIds = {1,4,8}
IQueryable<User> result = _database.User;

foreach (var item in statusIds)
   {
       result = result.Where(x => x.StatusId == item);
   }
```

This code only gets users with `StatusId` = 8.

Comment: Have you tried `result.Where(x => statusIds.contains( x.StatusId));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with serially using Where on the result of a Where like you do here:

```
foreach (var item in statusIds)
{
   result = result.Where(x => x.StatusId == item);
}
```

is that when you compound a Where on top of a previous Where, it functions as AND, not OR, so your query ends up the equivalent of:

```
_database.User.Where(u => u.StatusId == 1 && u.StatusId == 4 && u.StatusId == 8)
```

Naturally this will never produce any results because no records can be all 3 status simultaneously

Side note: you reported that the output is only the last element in the array, which I believe is a separate problem related to deferred execution and capture of foreach loop variable values (though I don't believe it would happen in modern C#). By the time the query is executed (which is after the loop finished) the loop variable has been used 3 times but the value used in the query is not the 3 different values the variable had during each loop iteration, but 3 repetitions of the single value it ended up with when the loop was over. As such, effectively, the query run is

```
_database.User.Where(u => u.StatusId == z && u.StatusId == z && u.StatusId == z)
```

and `z` has the value 8. Logically this can work as only one value is being tested.. You can read more about this particular oddity [here](https://unicorn-dev.medium.com/how-to-capture-a-variable-in-c-and-not-to-shoot-yourself-in-the-foot-d169aa161aa6)

Even if you put together a structure that coped with the "deferred execution using mutating captured loop variables" problem, you're still left with the "statusid = 1 and 4 and 8 must surely be false" problem, so you need another approach

---

Something like these will be mapped as `x IN (collection)`:

```
_database.User.Where(u => statusIds.Contains(u.StatusId))

_database.User.Where(u => statusIds.Any(sid => sid == u.StatusId))
```

Comment: Yes you are right,I didn't have any records with the status id 8 at that moment, so I thought output is records with status id 8.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem is given by @Greg in the question's comment.

I just wanted to formally layout the answer.

#### Approach 1

```
int[] statusIds = {1,4,8}
IQueryable<User> result = _database.User.Where(x => statusIds.Contains( x.StatusId));
```

#### Approach 2

```
int[] statusIds = {1,4,8}
IQueryable<User> result = _database.User.Where(x => statusIds.Any(n => n == x.StatusId));
```

The difference between the two approaches is that the `.Contains`    function is used when you need a SQL query similar to "**...WHERE x IN (1,2,3)**" result, which basically is a standard comparison situation.

While `.Any` allows you to provide your own predicate for either a multi-value compare or unique conditions. Do remember a predicate will execute locally which is a big no no if you have large dataset.

In general, try to avoid `.Any` as much as possible. The rule of thumb is to offload processing to the Database and not import all records and filter locally.

#### Debugging SQL Query

To see the actual SQL query being generated by EFCore (which I highly recommend), have a read on this [blog post](https://christianfindlay.com/2020/07/19/sql-generated-by-entity-framework-core/) by Christian Findlay.